# Unir varibles en rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio

necesito su ayuda para unir las dos columnas en una sola, en donde los NA sean reemplazados por los valores de la variable a la que corresponde, respectivamente.
Por ejemplo, tengo este caso (col_1 y col_2) y necesito que quede como la columna Col_3

| Col_1 | Col_2 | Col_3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | NA | A |
| NA | D | D |
| NA | A | A |
| NA | S | S |
| C | NA | C |
| D | NA | D |
| E | NA | E |
| A | NA | A |

Probé hacer esto:

```
   base%>%
        rowwise()%>%
        summarise(Comuna=sum(c(Col_1,Col_2),
                  na.rm=T))
```

Pero no me funciona porque son variables de tipo carácter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya que usas `dplyr`, si tienes que generar una nueva columna, el verbo es `mutate()` y para quedarte con el primer valor no `NA` entre ambas columnas puedes usar `coalesce()`:

```
base %>% 
  mutate(Comuna = coalesce(Col_1, Col_2))
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!